# Running multiple find+replace in sequence, is it possible?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I need to run a series of 3 regex find + replaces pretty regularly and was wondering if there's an easier way of doing this.

There's a plugin for Sublime which does what I want - RegReplace http://facelessuser.github.io/RegReplace/

Does anyone know if either there's a native way of doing this in WebStorm or a plugin for it?